# Updating sql database using pdo parameters - no errors - do nothing

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I know this topic has been discussed a lot in stackoverflow but I've read all topics I couldn't find a solution.

I've got this function which should update a mysql database. It justs do not do nothing, and do not show any errors. As you see I use PDO. I've seen lots of question similar to mine in stackoverflow, and tried their solution but none of them  seems to work.

I've checked that all variables that I pass to this function arrive and are correct.

```
public function updateValues($coreID, $table, $name, $time){
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {        
    $query_edit_user_name = $this->db_connection->prepare("UPDATE :tableT SET time = :timeT, name = :nameT WHERE id = :coreID");
    $query_edit_user_name->bindValue(':coreID', trim($coreID), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_edit_user_name->bindValue(':tableT', trim($table), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_edit_user_name->bindValue(':nameT', trim($name), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_edit_user_name->bindValue(':timeT', trim($time), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query_edit_user_name->execute();
}
}
```

I've been trying to add´´ or '' to different rows names or values but didn't worked. The only way it "works" is if there isn't a single PDO parameter:

```
    $query_edit_user_name = $this->db_connection->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET time = '55', name = 'name1' WHERE id = 'core2'");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a bind value or parameter for a table name.

```
$query_edit_user_name = $this->db_connection->prepare("UPDATE :tableT SET time...
                                                              ^^^^^^^
```

Try this instead:

```
public function updateValues($coreID, $table, $name, $time){
if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
$query_edit_user_name = $this->db_connection->prepare("UPDATE `$table` SET time = :timeT, name = :nameT WHERE id = :coreID");
$query_edit_user_name->bindValue(':coreID', trim($coreID), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_edit_user_name->bindValue(':nameT', trim($name), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_edit_user_name->bindValue(':timeT', trim($time), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query_edit_user_name->execute();
```

As has been pointed out in the comments, a dynamic table name is open to a possible injection, depending on where the table name is derived from.

Either, escape the table name before preparing the statement with something like:

```
$table = str_replace(array('\\',"\0" ,'`'), '', $table);
```

Or, use a whitelist method:

```
$allowed = array('table1', 'table2');
if (in_array($table, $allowed)) {
    // prepare and execute query
}
```

Comment: You might want to give more context here, but this is correct.  The context is a logical thoughtsexercise on how prepared statements actually work.  That being, how could MySQL possibly "prepare" a statement without knowing what database objects it is going to work against?

Comment: @MikeBrant you cannot ask every answer given to this question, which is asked twice a day, to be a comprehensive guide on prepared statements.

Comment: I'd say you made it worse. It will produce errors and allow injections.

Comment: You've got quite decent rep from this. I see no reason to complain.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: To be honest, other than whitelisting the table name before preparing the statement, I wouldn't know which way to go - do tell. For my own curiosity now above all else...

Comment: strictly speaking, table name can be sanitized, the same way as a string - by escaping delimiters. But whitelisting is still preferred

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Ah, how about now?